# Organic Groups - define content type to be of Group type

Tags: organic-groups

I am using the [Organic Groups](http://drupal.org/project/og) module and am following the readme file. I am on step 2 and already struggling...

Create a new content type via admin/structure/types/add. Call it "Group", and
   define it to be of Group type.

How do I define it to be of Group type?

I have enabled the following modules:
Entity Reference    7.x-1.0
Organic groups  7.x-2.0
Organic groups access control   7.x-2.0
Organic groups context  7.x-2.0
Organic groups field access 7.x-2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the create content type page you should have a vertical tab named `Organic Groups`. If this tab is missing, make sure you have enabled the `Organic groups UI` module. Clicking the `Organic Groups` tab reveals a couple of check boxes. Check the one for `Group` and hit save to make this content type a group which you can associate content with.

The other check box `Group content` defines that the content type can be posted into a group, i.e associated with the group you previously created.

To get you started you can also enable the `OG example` module.

The above is mainly for OG 7.2.

Comment: Thanks for that @enzipher

I can't see the Organic Groups vertical tab. Why would that be?

I am logged in as an administrator, and have the correct permission in admin/people/permissions for Administer Organic groups permissions.

Comment: @kine456 I believe this should be automatically set up when installing OG. Either reinstall OG if you think that would be an issue, or go to `Field settings` (`admin/config/group/fields`) and add the `Group` field to the `Node > Group` bundle. Check [this article](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/organic-groups-drupal-7) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. Will try reinstalling.

I can't even get to admin/config/group/fields ... :S

Comment: @kine456 I am almost sure the option should show up by default (I don't think they did for OG 7.1). You can always have a look at the [OG 7.2 documentation](http://drupal.org/node/1603460) as well.

Comment: @kine456 Also note that you need to enable Organic groups UI in order to see the vertical tab. You can also enable the og_example module to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Here are tutorials you might find very useful. Both are for (7.x-1.0). I've watch both many times & used them to build a demo site.

- if you're in a hurry
- Organic Groups Panels Walkthrough

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CqMEY6WMmtE&feature=youtu.be

if you've got time & want a more in depth approach

Nodeone : Learn Organic groups

> http://nodeone.se/sv/node/35